# Replace &amp or multiple &amp using regex

Tags: regex, ampersand

if only one &amp I could use

```
value = value.Replace("&amp;","&")
```

but as per checking the data, some has "&amp;amp" and many more.

Why is it decoded with multiple amp when original text is only one "&"?

I'm not a regex expert, I'd like to seek help to just create a regex that would decode it to only one ampersand.

Many thanks for those who will help :) Thanks

Comment: Trouble like this occurs in environments where HTML encoding and decoding is not in balance. Apparently there are still people who fail to see that HTML encoding is *not* idempotent, and assume it is better to encode/decode once too many than once too few. This situation made you lose track; now there is no way of knowing whether &amp; was the intended message, or just an encoding.

Comment: Were you accurate in saying the text is like `&amp;amp`, rather than `&amp;amp;`? If so, then there's only one match for the `amp;` grouping, which explains your results. If not, then please edit your question to be more accurate.

Comment: yah I've overlooked the data when trying to recreate it in lower environment, that's &amp;amp; Thanks! and sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to search for:

```
&(amp;)+
```

so:

```
value = value.Replace("&(amp;)+","&")
```

Comment: I've used stripped = Regex.Replace(HTMLToStrip, "&(amp;)+", "&") but it ends up replacing only the first &amp; weird!

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, as long as it is a String, you can use:

```
value = value.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");
```

This is strictly for the exact string "& amp ;" though.